# iPad+Detect whether image captured from front camera or rear camera

Tags: ipad, ios5, camera

I am developing an application for iPad where i am using camera to capture images,but i am facing problem when capturing images from REAR camera(they are being reversed),Else while capturing from FRONT camera,it works perfectly.Please Suggest solutions.Thanks in Advance:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean you have a mirror image from the front camera?
Check this [iPhone - Mirroring back a picture taken from the front camera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5505422/iphone-mirroring-back-a-picture-taken-from-the-front-camera)